# Basic python. How to forbid functions to change the list?

Tags: python, list, function

```
>>> def test():
...    a.remove(1)
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> test()
>>> print a 
[2]
```

Why does `a` equal `[2]` rather than `[1,2]`?

Comment: Please use code formatting next time, and look at the preview before posting questions.

Comment: This uses global variables, a pretty bad idea.  Where have you seen code examples like this before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List is mutable. If you pass it to a function, and the function changes it, it stays changed.

- Use an immutable structure: tuple: `a = (1,2)`
- Pass a copy of original list: `b = list(a); b.remove(1)` — now `a` and `b` have different contents, `a` hasn't changed.

Also, try not to use mutable global data. Either pass `a` to the function, or have `a` as an attribute of an object, and the function as its method.

Comment: You should not just think of a tuple as an immutable list. Python is not about controlling what the function does. The function doc string should tell you whether it modifies the parameters/globals etc. So +1 for suggesting to pass a copy, but -1 for switching to an immutable structure for this reason.

Comment: @gnibbler: Using an immutable structure prevents you from *accidental* modification of it. Python lacks almost any static checks, and you may want to be a bit defensive sometimes. Also, immutable structures can be easily shared and reused; sharing a mutable structure is always more tricky.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you want. Your test() function modifies the global 'a' list, so it's unsurprising that 'a' gets modified.

If you want 'test' to work on a copy of a instead directly on a, you may copy it first.

For example,

```
def test():
    a2 = list(a)
    a2.remove(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lists are mutable objects, they are meant to be changed. If you want to forbid changes, convert it to a tuple (e.g. `a = (1, 2)`) instead. Tuples are immutable, so it's not possible to change them without copying and re-assigning the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Because the list `a` exists in the global namespace and when you call a `remove` on it, the value `1` is removed.

If you don't want it to be modified, simply create a new list. If you call `remove` on the list `a`, of course it going to remove the value.